# (laravel) Como ignorar valores null no $request->all()?

Tags: php, laravel

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema de filtro em que o usuário pode ou não preencher alguns campos de um formulário.
No controller, estou tentando fazer um where da seguinte forma:

```
    //demais filtros
    $imoveis = Imovel::where([
        'finalidade' => $request['finalidade'],
        'tipo_id' => $request['tipo_id'],
        'cidade_id' => $request['cidade_id'],
        'bairro' => $request['bairro'],
        'area' => $request['area'],
        'quartos' => $request['quartos'],
        'banheiros' => $request['banheiros'],
        'suites' => $request['suites'],
        'garagens' => $request['garagens'],
    ])->get();
```

Porém, quero ignorar, de alguma forma, os valores que não foram preenchidos pelo usuário, e que vêm como null na request.

Um exemplo de dd($request->all()) é:

> array:14 [▼
>     "_token" => "NBFIYYW7XQFqR2j858Zq7sTliaQoYB0mZO1cKKnz"
>     "id" => null
>     "nome" => null
>     "finalidade" => "1"
>     "tipo_id" => null
>     "cidade_id" => null
>     "bairro" => null
>     "area" => null
>     "quartos" => null
>     "suites" => null
>     "banheiros" => null
>     "garagens" => null
>     "valorMinimo" => null
>     "valorMaximo" => null
>   ]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o helper [array_where](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-array-where).

Exemplo:

```
$a = ['a' => 'b', 'c' => null];

$filtered = array_where($a, function($value, $key){ 
 return !is_null($value); 
}); // ['a' => 'b']
```

Desta forma irá filtrar a array com todos os valores, retornando apenas os valores que não forem null.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta! Atendeu bem ao que eu precisava!

Answer (score 0):

Pode usar o in_array talvez, eu não sei laravel, mas acho que deve funcionar.

```
$minhaArray = array("Nome" => "Lucas", "id" => "1", "Idade" => null);

if(in_array(null, $minhaArray)){
  echo"teste1"; 
} else {
   echo "teste2";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Cara infelizmente o $request do Laravel não tem nenhum método que possa te ajudar, mas dá pra resolver isso de boa com a função *array_filter do PHP*.
A função *array_filter* filtra elementos de um array utilizando uma função de *callback*.

**Para resolver seu problema use o seguinte código**:

```
// No seu caso esse $array receberá o seu $request->all();
// $array = $request->all();


$array = ['name'=>'fulano','email'=>'fulano@mail.com','age'=>null];

// Vamos atribuir o retorno da função array_filter a uma nova variável
$fields = ( array_filter( $array , function( $value, $key ) {
    return $value != null; // retorna todos os valores que forem diferentes de null
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH ) );

echo  '<pre>';
print_r($fields);
die;

// Resultado da variável $fields
Array
(
    [name] => fulano
    [email] => fulano@mail.com
)
```

A função array_filter recebe 3 parâmetros, o primeiro será o array que você quer filtrar, o segundo será sua função de callback e o terceiro será a *flag(ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH )*.

Você pode dar uma olhada na documentação do *PHP* e entender melhor. ([Documentação](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-filter.php))